# Css selector for multiple td

Tags: html, css

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kwuvg923/)

```css
#strucmat tr:not(:first-child) td:not(:nth-child(1)), td:not(:nth-child(3)), td:not(:nth-child(8)) {
    background-color:red;
    text-align: center;
}
```

What I want to happen is: select all rows, except first row, the header, and select all `td`, except the first, third, and the eighth `td`.

Comment: Are you able to modify your HTML output so that your headers use `th` elements instead of `td` and apply classes to the first, third and eighth `td` elements? Then you could target `th, td.someClass { … }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to chain multiple `:not` selectors into one AND rule. So try this selector instead:

```css
#strucmat tr:not(:first-child) td:not(:nth-child(1)):not(:nth-child(3)):not(:nth-child(8)) {
    background-color: red;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kwuvg923/1/

Comment: why didnt it work when i specify that `td:not(:nth-child(1)), td:not(:nth-child(3)), td:not(:nth-child(8))`

Comment: Because even though the first part `#strucmat tr:not(:first-child) td:not(:nth-child(1))` of your selector was correct, then the next rules (`td:not(:nth-child(3))` and `td:not(:nth-child(8))`) effectively overwrites it. Because comma `,` between rules means OR, while you need AND.

Answer (score 0):

### Format your table semantically & strategically

If you are able to modify your HTML output, use semantic `th` tags to identify your header cells, and apply identifier classes to the first, third and eighth `td` elements.

This provides better structure for your code to promote maintainability and improves the performance of your CSS for faster rendering. You also gain cross-browser and legacy browser support.

You'll thank yourself later when you go to edit your CSS and you're not wasting time figuring out what you were trying to achieve with a convoluted, non-performant selector. ;)

```css
#strucmat th,
#strucmat td.roof,
#strucmat td.flooring,
#strucmat td.walls {
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" border="2" id="strucmat">
    <thead>
        <tr align="center">
            <th colspan="2">ROOF</th>
            <th>FLOORING</th>
            <th>1st
                <br>Flr.</th>
            <th>2nd
                <br>Flr.</th>
            <th>3rd
                <br>Flr.</th>
            <th>4th
                <br>Flr.</th>
            <th>Walls &amp; Partitions</th>
            <th>1st
                <br>Flr.</th>
            <th>2nd
                <br>Flr.</th>
            <th>3rd
                <br>Flr.</th>
            <th>4th
                <br>Flr.</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="roof">Reinforced Concrete</td>
            <td width="5%"> <span type="text" data-id="printroofReinforced Concrete" id="printroofreinforcedconcrete" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td class="flooring">Reinforced Concrete(for upper floors)</td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print1st FloorfloorReinforced Concrete" id="printfloorreinforcedconcrete1st" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print2nd FloorfloorReinforced Concrete" id="printfloorreinforcedconcrete2nd" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print3rd FloorfloorReinforced Concrete" id="printfloorreinforcedconcrete3rd" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print4th FloorfloorReinforced Concrete" id="printfloorreinforcedconcrete4th" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td class="walls">Reinforced Concrete</td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print1st FloorwallReinforced Concrete" id="printwallreinforcedconcrete1st" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print2nd FloorwallReinforced Concrete" id="printwallreinforcedconcrete2nd" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print3rd FloorwallReinforced Concrete" id="printwallreinforcedconcrete3rd" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print4th FloorwallReinforced Concrete" id="printwallreinforcedconcrete4th" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="roof">Tiles</td>
            <td width="5%" style="text-align: center;"> <span type="text" data-id="printroofTiles" data-id="printroofTiles" id="printrooftiles" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td class="flooring">Plain Cement</td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print1st FloorfloorPlain Cement" id="printfloorplaincement1st" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print2nd FloorfloorPlain Cement" id="printfloorplaincement2nd" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print3rd FloorfloorPlain Cement" id="printfloorplaincement3rd" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print4th FloorfloorPlain Cement" id="printfloorplaincement4th" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td class="walls">Plain Cement</td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print1st FloorwallPlain Cement" id="printwallplaincement1st" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print2nd FloorwallPlain Cement" id="printwallplaincement2nd" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print3rd FloorwallPlain Cement" id="printwallplaincement3rd" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print4th FloorwallPlain Cement" id="printwallplaincement4th" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="roof">G.I. Sheet</td>
            <td width="5%"> <span type="text" data-id="printroofG.I. Sheet" id="printroofGISheet" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td class="flooring">Marble</td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print1st FloorfloorMarble" id="printfloormarble1st" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print2nd FloorfloorMarble" id="printfloormarble2nd" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print3rd FloorfloorMarble" id="printfloormarble3rd" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print4th FloorfloorMarble" id="printfloormarble4th" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td class="walls">Wood</td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print1st FloorwallWood" id="printwallwood1st" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print2nd FloorwallWood" id="printwallwood2nd" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print3rd FloorwallWood" id="printwallwood3rd" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print4th FloorwallWood" id="printwallwood4th" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="roof">Aluminum</td>
            <td width="5%"> <span type="text" data-id="printroofAluminum" id="printfloorwood1st" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td class="flooring">Wood</td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print1st FloorfloorWood" id="printfloorwood1st" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print2nd FloorfloorWood" id="printfloorwood2nd" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print3rd FloorfloorWood" id="printfloorwood3rd" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print4th FloorfloorWood" id="printfloorwood4th" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td class="walls">CHB</td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print1st FloorwallCHB" id="printwallchb1st" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print2nd FloorwallCHB" id="printwallchb2nd" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print3rd FloorwallCHB" id="printwallchb3rd" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print4th FloorwallCHB" id="printwallchb4th" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="roof">Asbestos</td>
            <td width="5%"> <span type="text" data-id="printroofAsbestos" id="printroofasbestos" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td class="flooring">Tiles</td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print1st FloorfloorTiles" id="printfloortiles1st" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print2nd FloorfloorTiles" id="printfloortiles2nd" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print3rd FloorfloorTiles" id="printfloortiles3rd" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print4th FloorfloorTiles" id="printfloortiles4th" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td class="walls">G.I. Sheet</td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print1st FloorwallG.I. Sheet" id="printwallgisheet1st" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print2nd FloorwallG.I. Sheet" id="printwallgisheet2nd" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print3rd FloorwallG.I. Sheet" id="printwallgisheet3rd" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print4th FloorwallG.I. Sheet" id="printwallgisheet4th" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="roof">Long Span</td>
            <td width="5%"> <span type="text" data-id="printroofLong Span" id="printrooflongspan" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td class="flooring">Others(Specify)</td>
            <td>
                <br>
            </td>
            <td>
                <br>
            </td>
            <td>
                <br>
            </td>
            <td>
                <br>
            </td>
            <td class="walls">Build-a-wall</td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print1st FloorwallBuild-a-wall" id="printwallbuildawall1st" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print2nd FloorwallBuild-a-wall" id="printwallbuildawall2nd" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print3rd FloorwallBuild-a-wall" id="printwallbuildawall3rd" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print4th FloorwallBuild-a-wall" id="printwallbuildawall4th" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="roof">Concrete Desk</td>
            <td width="5%"> <span type="text" data-id="printroofConcrete Desk" id="printroofconcretedesk" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td class="flooring">
                <br>
            </td>
            <td>
                <br>
            </td>
            <td>
                <br>
            </td>
            <td>
                <br>
            </td>
            <td>
                <br>
            </td>
            <td class="walls">Sawali</td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print1st FloorwallSawali" id="printwallsawali1st" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print2nd FloorwallSawali" id="printwallsawali2nd" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print3rd FloorwallSawali" id="printwallsawali3rd" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print4th FloorwallSawali" id="printwallsawali4th" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="roof">Nipa/Anahaw/Cogon</td>
            <td width="5%"> <span type="text" data-id="printroofNipa/Anahaw/Cogon" id="printroofnipaanahawcogon" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td class="flooring">
                <br>
            </td>
            <td>
                <br>
            </td>
            <td>
                <br>
            </td>
            <td>
                <br>
            </td>
            <td>
                <br>
            </td>
            <td class="walls">Bamboo</td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print1st FloorwallBamboo" id="printwallbamboo1st" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print2nd FloorwallBamboo" id="printwallbamboo2nd" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print3rd FloorwallBamboo" id="printwallbamboo3rd" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
            <td> <span type="text" data-id="print4th FloorwallBamboo" id="printwallbamboo4th" class="center"></span>

                <br>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="roof">Others(Specify)</td>
            <td width="5%">
                <br>
            </td>
            <td class="flooring">
                <br>
            </td>
            <td>
                <br>
            </td>
            <td>
                <br>
            </td>
            <td>
                <br>
            </td>
            <td>
                <br>
            </td>
            <td class="walls">Others(Specify)</td>
            <td>
                <br>
            </td>
            <td>
                <br>
            </td>
            <td>
                <br>
            </td>
            <td>
                <br>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="roof">
                <br>
            </td>
            <td width="5%">
                <br>
            </td>
            <td class="flooring">
                <br>
            </td>
            <td>
                <br>
            </td>
            <td>
                <br>
            </td>
            <td>
                <br>
            </td>
            <td>
                <br>
            </td>
            <td class="walls">
                <br>
            </td>
            <td>
                <br>
            </td>
            <td>
                <br>
            </td>
            <td>
                <br>
            </td>
            <td>
                <br>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```